# Two-column layout has all contents under one column

Tags: html

Can someone help me to move my right column contents to the right, for some reason it’s wrapped under the left column

```
<section class="about" id="about">
        <div class="max-width">
            <h2 class="title"> About Us</h2>
            <div class="about-content">
                <div class="column left">
                   <img src="assets/images/AboutUs1.mp4" alt="">
                <div>
                <div class="column right">
                    <div class="text">We provide <span class="typing-2"></span> services</div>
                    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo, ex magni ducimus, numquam voluptates impedit nam cupiditate quidem, officiis inventore iure perferendis provident ipsam itaque! Architecto fugiat vitae odio facere? <p>
 
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo, ex magni ducimus, numquam voluptates impedit nam cupiditate quidem, officiis inventore iure perferendis provident ipsam itaque! Architecto fugiat vitae odio facere? <p>
                    <br>
                    <p>Contact us today to speak with a member of our team.</p>
                <div>
            <div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And the CSS for the left and right columns

```
.about .about-content .left{
    width: 25%;
}
.about .about-content .left img{
    max-height: 450px;
    max-width: 450px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.about .about-content .move{
    width: 55%;
}
.about .about-content .right .text{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-size: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.about .about-content .right .text span{
    color: crimson;
}
.about .about-content .right p{
    text-align: justify;
}
```

I’ve tried reformatting the code, when I inspected the elements, it appeared that the left column was the only one that is being registered and the right column is nested under it. Ideally it would be two columns with a left and a right one.

Comment: It's a typo. The `<div>` above `<div class="column right">` should've been `</div>`. There are more places in your code where you write `<div>` instead of `</div>`, near the end of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not closing `div.column.left`, once you close that `div`, the `div.column.right` will come out.

```css
.about .about-content .left{
    width: 25%;
}
.about .about-content {
    display: flex;
}
.about .about-content .left img{
    max-height: 450px;
    max-width: 450px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.about .about-content .move{
    width: 55%;
}
.about .about-content .right .text{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-size: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.about .about-content .right .text span{
    color: crimson;
}
.about .about-content .right p{
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<section class="about" id="about">
        <div class="max-width">
            <h2 class="title"> About Us</h2>
            <div class="about-content">
                <div class="column left">
                   <img src="assets/images/AboutUs1.mp4" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="column right">
                    <div class="text">We provide <span class="typing-2"></span> services</div>
                    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo, ex magni ducimus, numquam voluptates impedit nam cupiditate quidem, officiis inventore iure perferendis provident ipsam itaque! Architecto fugiat vitae odio facere? <p>
 
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo, ex magni ducimus, numquam voluptates impedit nam cupiditate quidem, officiis inventore iure perferendis provident ipsam itaque! Architecto fugiat vitae odio facere? <p>
                    <br>
                    <p>Contact us today to speak with a member of our team.</p>
                <div>
            <div>
        </div>
    </section>
```